# How to skip the null value of a column while creating the dense rank in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dense-rank

I have to create dense rank based on the value of a column. That column has some null value and some float values. I have to skip null value and concentrate on float values. I am not sure how to do this?
Can you please help me for doing this?

Explain:

df:

```
  comb_fld_order
0     NULL
1     NULL
2     NULL
3     1.1
4     1.1
5     NULL
```

I am using below code to creating dense rank-

```
df['dense_rank'] = df.groupby('comb_fld_order', sort=True).ngroup()+1
```

It is giving me output:

```
   comb_fld_order   dense_rank
0     NULL            2
1     NULL            2
2     NULL            2
3     1.1             1
4     1.1             1
5     NULL            2
```

But I want below output:

```
   comb_fld_order   dense_rank
0     NULL            
1     NULL            
2     NULL            
3     1.1             1
4     1.1             1
5     NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter out `NaN` values with `.notnull()` prior to using `.groupby`
2. Then, use `fillna('')` if you want blanks instead of `NaN`

---

```
import pandas as pd
df['dense_rank'] = df[df['comb_fld_order'].notnull()].groupby('comb_fld_order', sort=True).ngroup()+1
df['dense_rank'] = df['dense_rank'].fillna('')
df
Out[1]: 
   comb_fld_order dense_rank
0             NaN           
1             NaN           
2             NaN           
3             1.1          1
4             1.1          1
5             NaN
```

If `NULL` is a string, then you can do:

```
df['dense_rank'] = df[df['comb_fld_order'] != 'NULL'].groupby('comb_fld_order', sort=True).ngroup()+1
```

Comment: I already used df = df.fillna('') before creating the dense_rank. I tried with your suggestion but not getting the desirable result.

Comment: @shivampatel Try: `df['dense_rank'] = df[df['comb_fld_order'] != 'NULL'].groupby('comb_fld_order', sort=True).ngroup()+1`

Comment: @DavidErickson IMHO u can simply use `df['comb_fld_order'].rank(method='dense').fillna('')` :) +1

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma , I have never used `.rank()` before. Doesn't surprise me that there is a simple pandas method for this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give dropna=True

Here's what I did.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'comb_fld_order':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.1, 1.1, np.nan]})
>>> df
   comb_fld_order
0             NaN
1             NaN
2             NaN
3             1.1
4             1.1
5             NaN
>>> df['dense_rank'] = df.groupby('comb_fld_order', sort=True,dropna=True).ngroup()+1
>>> df
   comb_fld_order  dense_rank
0             NaN           0
1             NaN           0
2             NaN           0
3             1.1           1
4             1.1           1
5             NaN           0
```